# Automate saving received files in Teams chat

Tags: power-automate, o365-flow

for any file that is sent to me via Teams chat, is there a way to trigger a flow to save it somewhere (one drive, sharepoint, etc)?

I would like to capture files sent to me from all chats.

Thanks!

Brook

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you'll find that they're already saved in your OneDrive instance.
When you think about it, they have to exist somewhere.

Try this ... go to your tenant URL but instead of using the main link, use your **my** link.

```
https://<your_tenant>-my.sharepoint.com/
```

[image: Chat Files]

If you can't work out what the URL is, go into Teams and find a chat that you know has had files exchanged previously.

From that chat, go to the **Files** tab.

[image: Files]

Click on the three dots next to any file and select **Copy Link**, in there, you'll find the base URL that will give you the folder where all of the your files are stored.